# Web Driver failed to open an application in safari browser

Tags: java, selenium, safari, selenium-webdriver

I tried to run a test on `Safari` browser. Browser opens well but it failed to launch the application.

Selenium Standalone Version: 2.39.0
Safari - 5.1.7
OS - Windows

Code used to launch

```
WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
driver.get("some application url");
```

Safari window opens with the following message

```
SafariDriver Client

[  0.504s] [safaridriver.client] Requesting connection at ws://localhost:7539...  
[  0.647s] [safaridriver.client] Request acknowledged; connecting...
```

**Log:**

```
Mar 26, 2014 2:56:05 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer start
INFO: Server started on port 7539
Mar 26, 2014 2:56:07 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor start
INFO: Launching Safari
Mar 26, 2014 2:56:07 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor start
INFO: Waiting for SafariDriver to connect
Mar 26, 2014 2:56:13 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverChannelHandler$1operationComplete
INFO: Connection opened
Mar 26, 2014 2:56:14 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor start
INFO: Driver connected in 6154 ms


org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: The driver is not focused on a window. You  must switch to a window before proceeding. (WARNING: The server did not provide any     stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 19 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:11:15'
System info: host: 'QA02', ip: '192.168.18.58', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_21'
Session ID: null
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, javascriptEnabled=true,  secureSsl=true, browserName=safari, takesScreenshot=true, version=5.1.7}]
```

Please guide me how to resolve the issue

Comment: do you have safari installed on the machine?

Comment: Installed. Verison - 5.1.7(7534.57.2)

Comment: did you find any solution here?